# Cordova 3.5 plugin permission error(rm: could not remove file (code EACCES)

Tags: cordova

This is my first time i'm using cordova and phonegap. I have tried the two and none of them is working for me. For phonegap latest documentation, you don't need to install some plugins they are already bundle with it. Like the device,contact,network-information and from the android configuration permissions are already been given to them.

And the problem i have with cordova 3.5(latest) is when i install plugin and try to build or run i have permission problem and if i give the plugin directory a permission then these error pop up

```
   rm: could not remove file (code EACCES):    /home/bright/helloTest/platforms/android/assets/www/cordova.js

  rm: could not remove file (code EACCES):  /home/bright/helloTest/platforms/android/assets/www/cordova.js
  rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /home/bright/helloTest/platforms/android/assets/www/cordova_plugins.js

  rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /home/bright/helloTest/platforms/android/assets/www/cordova.js
  rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /home/bright/helloTest/platforms/android/assets/www/cordova_plugins.js
  rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /home/bright/helloTest/platforms/android/assets/www/css/index.css
```

And if run or build with root permission i get this error:

```
  Running command: /home/bright/helloTest/platforms/android/cordova/run 
  ERROR: Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to  your path.
  Error: /home/bright/helloTest/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit  code 2
  at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-  lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
  at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
  at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:5)
```

but when no plugin is install it runs perfectly. 
I'm using ubuntu 12.04.

And why is the phonegap(latest) plugins not working, i mean the default APIs(contact,geolocation,device,network-information,notification and the rest)

I would be grateful if point me on right path, i spent great deal of time on this issue for days trying to make this work. Thank You in advance,

Comment: have you installed `ant` it is giving the error `ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed`. You need to install ant and add it to your $PATH. Also create a variable $ANT_HOME.

Comment: Thank for ur quick reply, Yes i have done that,  Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on May 18 2012

Comment: when u r running using root permission check whether **ant** program is accessible by typing **ant** at the **$** prompt. Also the path variables should be available/set during the root session.

Comment: I tried issuing ant at the root session and it said,              Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin/bin/java.  why is that i'm able to build and run without a plugins been installed

Comment: How do i properly correct the problem above or the JAVA_HOME becos i have done dat

Comment: My concern is why is phonegap can build and run perfectly but i can use the API or plugins.

Comment: i was able to go around, i used cordova to install plugins and build and run it with phonegap. cordova plugin add (the plugin you want to add go here). Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Just run in root project via terminal:

```
sudo chown username * -R
```

If not works, run:

```
sudo chmod +777 -R
```

*username = your username in OS

Comment: You should change "-R" location in command like so: sudo chown -R username *